# IE6 on Windows 7 X64

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer-6

Im looking for a x64 version of IE6... As a web developer there are still some really outdated big companies who use it on their intranet.

I have been tasked to re-work some of the internal web-apps but i cant find an IE6 version which actually works.

Now the reason why im asking here, I know there is a Microsoft product which allows you to view a web-app / website in all kinds of browsers, while still being able to debug it.

But i cant remember the darn Applications name, been searching for the last 2 days, can anyone help me out here?

Edit : I would really like the microsoft product's name if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options that come to mind

- Use a [VM with IE 6](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads)
- Simulate an IE6 experience using [modern.ie](http://www.modern.ie/en-us) (if your site is publicly visible)
- Use a service like [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/)
- Use a tool like [IE Tester](http://ietester.en.softonic.com/) (beware that this does have difference between actual IE 6)

Of course using online services depends whether your application is publicly visible.

Answer (score 0):

I use this all the time [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)
It allows you to test in IE9, IE8, IE7 IE 6 and IE5.5

EDIT: 
Modern.ie is actually a microsoft website it allows you to test your website online and download virtual pc images to test localy.

Maybe you're thinking about [Microsoft Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36179). 
Microsoft Expression Web SuperPreview is designed to streamline testing websites in IE8, IE7 and IE6.